# My handwritten C++ Makefile gives command not found

Tags: compiling, make

I made a makefile to help compile multiple C++ files, but it is giving me "command not found" errors. I need to fix it.

The errors I get:

```
Make: line 1: main.out::command not found 
g++: error: GradeBook.o: No such file or directory 
g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory 
g++: fatal error: no input files 
compilation terminated. 
Make: line 4: main.o:: command not found 
Make: line 7: GradeBook.o:: command not found 
Make: line 10: clear:: command not found
```

Here is my makefile:

```
main.out: GradeBook.o main.o
    g++ -Wall -g -o main.out GradeBook.o main.o 

main.o: main.cpp GradeBook.h
    g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp

GradeBook.o: GradeBook.cpp GradeBook.h
    g++ -Wall -g -c GradeBook.cpp

clean:
    rm -f main.out main.o GradeBook.o
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a list of typical mistakes people make with makefiles.

#### Issue #1 - using spaces instead of tabs

The command `make` is notoriously picky about the formatting in a `Makefile`. You'll want to make sure that the action associated with a given target is prefixed by a tab and not spaces.

That is a single <kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by the command you want to run for a given target.

#### Example

This being your target.

```
main.out: GradeBook.o main.o
```

The command that follows should have a single <kbd>Tab</kbd> in front of it.

```
    g++ -Wall -g -o main.out GradeBook.o main.o 
^^^^--Tab
```

#### Here is your Makefile cleaned up

```
//Here is my makefile:

main.out: GradeBook.o main.o
        g++ -Wall -g -o main.out GradeBook.o main.o 

main.o: main.cpp GradeBook.h
        g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp

GradeBook.o: GradeBook.cpp GradeBook.h
        g++ -Wall -g -c GradeBook.cpp

clean:
        rm -f main.out main.o GradeBook.o
```

#### Issue #2 - naming it wrong

The tool `make` is expecting the file to be called `Makefile`. Anything else, you need to tell `make` what file you want it to use.

```
$ make -f mafile

-or- 

$ make --file=makefile

-or-

$ make -f smurfy_makefile
```

**NOTE:** If you name your file `Makefile`, then you can get away with just running the command:

```
$ make
```

#### Issue #3 - Running Makefiles

`Makefile`'s are data files to the command `make`. They aren't executables.

#### Example

*make it executable*

```
$ chmod +x makefile
```

*run it*

```
$ ./makefile 
./makefile: line 1: main.out:: command not found
g++: error: GradeBook.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./makefile: line 4: main.o:: command not found
g++: error: main.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./makefile: line 7: GradeBook.o:: command not found
g++: error: GradeBook.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./makefile: line 10: clean:: command not found
```

#### Other isues

Beyond the above tips I'd also advice you to make heavy use of `make`'s ability to do "dry-runs" or "test mode". The switches:

```
   -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
        Print the commands that would be executed, but do not execute them 
        (except in certain circumstances).
```

#### Example

Running the file `makefile`.

```
$ make -n -f makefile 
g++ -Wall -g -c GradeBook.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -c main.cpp
g++ -Wall -g -o main.out GradeBook.o main.o
```

But notice that none of the resulting files were actually created when we ran this:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml   0 Dec 22 08:39 GradeBook.cpp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml   0 Dec 22 08:45 GradeBook.h
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml   0 Dec 22 08:45 main.cpp
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 saml saml 262 Dec 22 08:25 makefile
```

Comment: sorry, that is exactly what I did. But there are still problems.

Comment: @Bruce - can you include the errors then in your Q? We need more info. to debug this further.

Comment: I typed what was shown in unix above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Bruce - see updates.

Comment: Just a second thought, adding a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/make -f` to the first line of a Makefile should make it work as an executable. (Not using `env` because shebang with spaces is a terrible mess)

Answer (score 0):

From the error messages, it appears you're running your Makefile as if it was an executable or shell script (i.e. you've set the executable bit and run `./Make`).

That's not how its done. You need to invoke `make` to run your Makefile, i.e.:

```
$ make -f Make
```

Or if you rename your file to `Makefile`, you can simply type:

```
$ make
```